# Segue Out of Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to leave the initial view controller, and go into the blank view controller. That is fine, but that would make the blank view controller also part of the navigation controller, which is not what I want. I want to segue out of the view controller.

In the view controller I try to segue out of, it pops it self, and when I try the method in the view will appear of the target view controller, `self.navigationController?.topViewController` returns itself, but `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(animated)` doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a `navigationController` do

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
```

Otherwise do

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

**Update**

Go to your Storyboard, select the ViewController you want to navigate to and add a storyboard id. Make sure the click "Use Storyboard ID"
[image]

Go to the class you want to navigate from and add the following code

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
// vc is the Storyboard ID that you added
// as! ... Add your ViewController class name that you want to navigate to
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc") as! ViewController
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
})
```

Add this code in the action that you use when you want to navigate.

Comment: Yes when you want to leave the controller, add one of the rows above in the action.

Comment: Ok, well I did the first one, but I feel like it is removing the wrong view controller, because that is not working.

Comment: You should add that row in the viewController that you want to close.

Comment: I did that, but it is popping itself from the navigation controller

Comment: Yeah so, in the view controller I try to segue out of, it pops it self, and when I try the method in the view will appear of the target view controller, `self.navigationController?.topViewController` returns itself, but `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(animated)` doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried to make a segue between the ViewControllers? A simple push segue and then you call self.performSegueWithIdentifier?

Comment: That's what I am doing currently, but that still makes the target view controller a part of the navigation controller

Comment: Don´t really understand what you mean by "makes the target view controller a part of the navigation controller"

Comment: I meant that if you segue from a View Controller that is embedded in a Navigation Controller, then the View Controller that you are segueing to will, by default, also embed that into the View Controller.

Comment: @SaketramDurbha, sorry I misunderstood you.  Check the updated code it will help you.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this can be done without having to write any code at all. To Segue out of a Navigation Controller follow these steps:

1. Create a Segue from the View Controller that has a Navigation Controller as it's root view controller to the View Controller that you would like to go to next (without being inside the Navigation Controller)
2. Click on the new Seque
3. Open the Attributes Inspector
4. Choose 'Kind' -> 'Present Modally'
5. Choose 'Present' -> 'Over Current Context'

[image]

Comment: This the navigation controller not be released. You can still see the navigation views under the modal view.

Comment: I think this is a poor answer to the question, you are not disposing of the navigation controller stack